# div positioning with 100% height

Tags: html, css, dom

I want to have this layout like this

[image]

The nav should be fixed and the height of the div with the background-image 100%.
Below the image I want to add the content.

My problem is - when i set the div of the image positioning 'relative' then i cant set the hight to 100%

```css
.container ul {
 margin-left: 50px;
}

.nav {
 background-color: #D3D3D3;
 height: 40px;
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 opacity: 0.6;
}

.nav li {
 display: inline;
}

a {
 color: white;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 padding-left: 20px;
 font-family: "Comic Sans MS", "Comic Sans", cursive;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.jumbotron {
 background-size: cover;
 background-image: url('http://www.apothekenkurier.de/uploads/pics/haut.rg.jpg');
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

.content {
 height: 100px;
 background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="container">
    <ul class="pull-left">
      <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
  
<div class="jumbotron">
</div>

<div class="content">
</div>
```

Comment: Could try `height : 100vh;` instead of % [viewport width/height](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)

Comment: Yeah! It works - but what is the difference between vh and %?

Comment: That doesn't work in all the Browsers. Why must it be a relative position?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Answer (score 1):

### Image Ratio with Padding

I think this is what you are looking for

```
.jumbotron {
  background-size: cover;
  background-image: url('http://www.apothekenkurier.de/uploads/pics/haut.rg.jpg');
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0; /* Changed */
  padding-bottom: 75%; /* height:width ratio */
}
```

[Responsive elements that retain their aspect ratio](http://jonathannicol.com/blog/2011/10/18/responsive-elements-that-retain-their-aspect-ratio/)